# Javascript / jQuery changing cell of a table based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have a javascript function that take the contents of a JSON file and the puts it in to a table, here is the code.

```
$.getJSON("People.json",
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.People, function(i, PersonObj) {
            var Person = PersonObj[Object.keys(PersonObj)[0]];
            content = '<tr>';
            content += '<tbody>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.Op + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.Name + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.WorkHours + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.Start + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.End + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.Clock + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.OFF + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.ON + ' </td>';
            content += '<td>' + Person.OUT + ' </td>';
            content += '</tr>';
            content += '</tbody>';
            content += '<p>';
            $(content).appendTo("tbody");
            console.log(Person);
        });
    });
```

However what i need is to some formatting via if statements so for example

normally i would use something like the badly put together bunch of If statements.

```
if (Person.clock !== false) {
document.getElementById('the cell where Person.Op is placed').style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
}
if (Person.Off !== false) {
document.getElementById('the cell where Person.Op is placed').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
if (Person.on !== false) {
document.getElementById('the cell where Person.Op is placed').style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
}
if (Person.out !== false) {
document.getElementById('the cell where Person.Op is placed').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

However i am struggling to find the best way of putting what i already have with the function for creating the table and putting the formatting from the If statements together
 what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: You should put the background-color picking logic into a function, which is passed the Person object and returns a color based on that. Then you can have somthing like `content += '<td style="background-color:' + getBgColorByPerson(Person) + '">' + Person.Op + '</td>`;

Comment: Your HTML doesn't make sense. Your `<tbody>` and `<tr>` are improperly nested, `<p>` doesn't belong in a table outside of a cell, and `tbody` elements shouldn't be appended to other `tbody`s.

Comment: Offtopic: Cool kids do not change DOM inside a loop.

Comment: @Blazemonger the <p> is something from earlier that i have forgotten to  remove, and the tbody that is being appended to is empty so it's just filling it in

Answer (score 3):

Why not add a class to each such case. something like this:

```
       $.getJSON("People.json",
            function(data) {
                $.each(data.People, function(i, PersonObj) {
                    var Person = PersonObj[Object.keys(PersonObj)[0]];
                    content = '<tr>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.Op + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.Name + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.WorkHours + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.Start + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.End + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td class="'+(Person.clock? 'hasClock' : '') +'">' + Person.Clock + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.OFF + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.ON + ' </td>';
                    content += '<td>' + Person.OUT + ' </td>';
                    content += '</tr>';
                    $(content).appendTo("tbody");
                    console.log(Person);
                });
            });
```

and then add a class to your css:

```
.hasClock{ 
    background-color :lime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON("People.json",
                function(data) {
                    $.each(data.People, function(i, PersonObj) {
                        var Person = PersonObj[Object.keys(PersonObj)[0]];
                        content = '<tr>';
                        content += '<tbody>';
                        content += '<td class="op ' + Person.Op + '">' + Person.Op + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.Name + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.WorkHours + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.Start + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.End + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.Clock + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.OFF + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.ON + ' </td>';
                        content += '<td>' + Person.OUT + ' </td>';
                        content += '</tr>';
                        content += '</tbody>';
                        content += '<p>';
                        $(content).appendTo("tbody");
                        console.log(Person);
                    });
                });
```

Add class to your td's with the value. If you have definite values coming up, then you can create css selectors for that with the CSS properties you want.

Suppose you had value of op as someOpValue
You could write your css like foloowing.

```
td.op.someOpValue{
    background : red;
}
```